# How to convert Sympy formulas like "arctg(5)+..." to float values in list?

Tags: python, matrix, typeerror, sympy

I have system of differential equations. I must do the Jacobian Matrix, and get it to the method, to find the stability step by using 2/max(abs(eigenvalue)) = hst

I am trying to make it like this

```
x, y, z = symbols("x y z")


J = Function('J')(x, y, z)
#Setting the Jacobian matrix elements


f1_swpx_angle_ball_step1 = 'arctg(x)'  
print(f1_swpx_angle_ball_step1)
f1_swpy_angle_ball_step1 = 'y/(x*x+1)' 
print(f1_swpx_angle_ball_step1)
f1_swpz_angle_ball_step1 = '0'  
print(f1_swpx_angle_ball_step1)
f2_swpx_angle_ball_step1 = '-3*arctg(x)' 
print(f2_swpx_angle_ball_step1)
f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1 = '-3*(x+3.27)/(y*y+1)'  
print(f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1)
f2_swpz_angle_ball_step1 = '0'      
print(f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1)
f3_swpx_angle_ball_step1 = "1/(x*x+1)"       
print(f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1)
f3_swpy_angle_ball_step1 = "0"       
print(f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1)
f3_swpz_angle_ball_step1 = "(0)"       
print(f3_swpz_angle_ball_step1)
```

```
#Setting the Jacobian matrix elements
F3_switchball_angle_step1 = Matrix([[f1_swpx_angle_ball_step1, f1_swpy_angle_ball_step1, f1_swpz_angle_ball_step1],
                                    [f2_swpx_angle_ball_step1, f2_swpy_angle_ball_step1, f2_swpz_angle_ball_step1],
                                    [f3_swpx_angle_ball_step1, f3_swpy_angle_ball_step1, f3_swpz_angle_ball_step1]])
```

getting some values from print

```
jaceiglist = list(JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())
print(jaceiglist)

[-0.5*sqrt(1.0*arctg(5)**2 - 0.399230769230769*arctg(5) + 0.910556360946746) + 0.5*arctg(5) - 0.477115384615385, 0.5*sqrt(1.0*arctg(5)**2 - 0.399230769230769*arctg(5) + 0.910556360946746) + 0.5*arctg(5) - 0.477115384615385, 0]
```

```
#trying to make a method, that get differentiable variables, and substituting the values, will calculate the current Jacobi matrix and the stability step

def hstabilitygetting_angle_ball_step1(MatrixForYacobian, values):
    print("Matrix Shape ",MatrixForYacobian.shape)
    JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1 = Matrix(
    MatrixForYacobian.subs([(x, values[0]), (y, values[1]), (z, values[2])]))
    print("Jacobian Matrix shape after substitute", JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.shape)

    jaceiglist = list(JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())
    print("Eigenvalues",jaceiglist)
    return 2 / (reduce(lambda x, y: abs(x) if abs(x) > abs(y) else abs(y), jaceiglist))
```

I can't make this list values to float

```
JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1 = sympy.Matrix(F3_switchball_angle_step1.subs([(x,5),(y,5),(z,0)])) 
jaceiglist = list(JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals()) print(jaceiglist) eq=sympy.S(str(jaceiglist[0])) eq.subs(sympy.Function('arctg'), sympy.atan ) eq.subs(sympy.Function('sqrt'), math.sqrt) 
print((eq).evalf(),'Value') 
eq = ((eq).evalf())
```

getting

```
-0.5*(1.0*arctg(5)**2 - 0.399230769230769*arctg(5) + 0.910556360946746)**0.5 + 0.5*arctg(5) - 0.477115384615385
```

This is an expression, and I need to make it float, get max(abs(values list), to have stability step.

```
print(float((eq).evalf()),'Value') TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float
```

Comment: Looks like jaceiglist contains sympy expressions that can't be converted to simple true/false values - or rather used in `>` relations that give these values.

Comment: Can they be converted to just float values, to get max from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When expressions involving `arctg` were sympified, unknown functions of that name were created. You should replace them with `atan`:

```
>>> eq=S('-3*arctg(x)')
>>> eq.subs(Function('arctg'), atan)
-3*atan(x)
```

Maybe like this:

```
>>> jaceiglist = Tuple(*JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())
...  .subs(Function('arctg'), atan)
```

Comment: Did not got the idea, what is S() 
and Tuple( * ) doesn't work for me, tuple( * ) says, that it got 3 arguments, but waited 1.

And if I try something like


jaceiglist = tuple(JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())
eq = (jaceiglist)
eq.subs((Function('arctg'), sympy.atan))
print("Test", eq)

It says

    eq.subs((Function('arctg'), sympy.atan))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'subs' 

@smichr

Comment: `from sympy import S, Tuple`

Comment: Thanks, @OscarBenjamin, but, still don't work.

jaceiglist = Tuple(*JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())
eq = S(jaceiglist)
eq.subs((Function('arctg'), sympy.atan))
print("Test", eq)

Gives error
  eq.subs((Function('arctg'), sympy.atan))
  File "D:\Modified_Runge_Kutta_Step_By_Eiler\venv\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\basic.py", line 903, in subs
    if isinstance(s[0], str):
TypeError: 'UndefinedFunction' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @smichr 
trying to do
JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1 = sympy.Matrix(F3_switchball_angle_step1.subs([(x,5),(y,5),(z,0)]))

jaceiglist = list(JacobianF_falling_angle_ball_step1.eigenvals())

print(jaceiglist)

eq=sympy.S(str(jaceiglist[0]))
eq.subs(sympy.Function('arctg'), sympy.atan )
eq.subs(sympy.Function('sqrt'), math.sqrt)
print((eq).evalf(),'Value')
eq = ((eq).evalf())

getting
-0.5*(1.0*arctg(5)**2 - 0.399230769230769*arctg(5) + 0.910556360946746)**0.5 + 0.5*arctg(5) - 0.477115384615385
print(float((eq).evalf()),'Value')
TypeError: Cannot convert expression to float

Comment: SymPy doesn't do replacements in-place so you either have to save the new expression or do all replacements at once: `eq = eq.subs({sympy.Function('arctg'): sympy.atan, sympy.Function('sqrt'):math.sqrt})` You can also tell `S` to use certain functions for certain names, `S('atn(x)',locals={'atn': sympy.atan}) -> atan(x)`.